# i can't access my openwrt router even after reset configuration in failsafe mode

Tags: configuration, router, openwrt

my router is linksys WRT54GL with backfire os. i already try reset with "firstboot" and "mtd -r erase rootfs_data" , after reboot i still can't access it with static ip address or dhcp. 
sorry for my bad english, Please help

Comment: Try reseting using the reset button, if not working share the Led color and connection details.

Comment: thanks for ur suggest but i already hit the reset button to enter failsafe mode, in failsafe mode i try to reset configuration but not work. when i try to "ping" the message is "network unreachable" and sometime " request time out"

Comment: Share your network configuration file(/etc/config/network)

Comment: i think u can help to solve this problem. i can't access my router cause i have failed configure network then i try to restore my old config on failsafe mode but not work. finally i reset all configuration and this my network configuration now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFuJ7.png
@VivekD  thanks for ur attention

Comment: Connect pc with port 4 of router. Assign static ip to pc of range 192.168.1.x, then access the router gui on 192.168.1.1

Comment: i have already try all port but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can solve my problem with flashing router and clean the nvram. i use openwrt brcm24 http://downloads.openwrt.org/whiterussian/newest/default/openwrt-brcm-2.4-squashfs.trx and flash with this script http://downloads.openwrt.org/people/nbd/nvram-clean.sh.
use `mtd -r write openwrt-brcm-2.4-squashfs.trx linux` to flash ,reboot then
`./nvram-clean.sh`  and  `nvram commit` to clean nvram
more info : https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe